# What's inside a reed switch that cannot be tested with a multimeter?

Tags: switches, measurement

I'm shopping for reed contacts that are rated for 230V AC, because I don't want to use an always-on power supply just for a relay and a reed switch. This is surprisingly difficult, but I found this product:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-NC-Magnetic-Proximity-Contact-Reed-Switch-AC-110-220V-for-Door/253489168964

[image: reed contact]

In the description it says:

> Note: The multimeter can not be used to test the opening and closing of the door switch.

What does that tell me about the inner workings of this thing?

Comment: It sounds a bit chinglishish but it might mean that the contacts have a minimal wetting current. Bottom line: never buy things without a proper datasheet.

Comment: A datsheet is like a CV, without a CV no one would hire you, without a datsheet you *shouldn't* buy it. *Common sense*.

Comment: The specifications in that particular listing are about 5 times more detailed than you can find on typical magnetic door switches. See this [pathetic excuse](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Adafruit%20PDFs/375_Web.pdf) for datasheet, for example. But yes, I agree that this is most likely a reference to wetting current. Common for reeds since mercury wetting has been banned

Comment: Has anyone seen a reed switch operated thyristor that is encapsulated?  They would also fail testing at low voltages and DC.